I am unable to attend the death ceremony of my blood relation then what how should I observe as per Hinduism?
I don't have any connection with my family relatives but after hearing demise of my relative, I felt sorry and want to observe the 10 days but I am not allowed to participate in their family and the rituals. How can I observe the 10 days by myself?

One of the easiest ways would be to do Nama Japa or Kirtan of Lord Krishna (e.g., Hare Krishna Maha Mantra) or Lord Shiva (e.g., Samba Sadashiva) daily for a set duration (e.g., 30 minutes) or hear Their glories from the Shastras.
One should hear Shastras such as Shrimad Bhagavatam, Mahabharata, etc. from a genuine Sadhu who is himself fully self-realized.
Below are some DONTs for best results.

Consuming meat including onion and garlic
Illicit sex as well as such sights
Gambling
Intoxication (alcohol as well as tea and coffee)
Harboring envy or hate towards any living entity

This would liberate the soul of the deceased or at the minimum save them from suffering during their journey ahead and also benefit one's own soul.

sarveṣām apy aghavatām
idam eva suniṣkṛtam
nāma-vyāharaṇaṁ viṣṇor
yatas tad-viṣayā matiḥ

Simply by chanting the holy name of Lord Viṣṇu, anyone
may attract the attention of the Supreme Lord, who therefore
considers, "Because this person has chanted My holy name, My duty is to
give him or her protection. - Shrimad Bhagavatam 6.2.9-10

More glories of the holy name of Lord Krishna.
